# When I select a feature within a vector layer (polygon), multiple features are selected. How can I de-link these separate features?

Tags: qgis, polygon

When I select a feature within a vector layer (polygon), separate features also get selected. This occurs using the 'identify features' tool and 'select features' tool. I need to label these sections differently. I am trying to find out why this happens, and how to separate these features so that I can deal with them independently.

[image]

Comment: You have muli-part polygon features. You can run the Multipart to singleparts algorithm in the processing toolbox to convert to singlepart features.

Comment: @BenW Thanks, that's perfect

Answer (score 2):

Just to avoid keeping the question unanswered, as commented by @[Ben W](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/100254/ben-w):

> You have multi-part polygon features. You can run the Multipart to
> singleparts algorithm in the processing toolbox to convert to
> singlepart features.

You can find it in `Processing Toolbox → Vector geometries → Multipart to singleparts`

[image]

If `Edit Features in-place` is clicked, running `Multipart to singleparts` will modify the features in place without creating a new layer.

Comment: I do not know why @BenW did  not put his comment as a valid answer :) Luckily you did !